# Multiple Header in radgrid with static header and 2 rows of custom header

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am using telerik radgrid(asp.net) with multiple headers.(3 rows of headers)
I have 2 requirements:

1. Freeze header,so that vertical scrolling can be done without losing sight of header.
2. This grid has lot of columns, and above the tpopmost header row there is another 2 rows of controls outside the grid. I want to include them in the grid header so that when horizontal scrolling is done, those controls should also be visible for each column.

Comment: Please take a look at this : [Telerik demo on scrolling](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/scrolling/scrolling/defaultcs.aspx). 
So the solution is give a size to your grid.  Put scrolling to true. And thats it. For the row of control you can use [CommandeItemTemplate](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/commanditem/defaultcs.aspx) it will be on top of the grid so if we see hearder we see them.

Comment: Thanks for response. The controls are coming in the grid, but the problem is that they dont scroll horizontally along with the grid. I need the control row also to scroll with the header

Comment: Use the scrolling property of your grid. its in Grid >ClientSettings >Scrolling > AllowScroll. M pretty sure thats what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you so much..its working :)